# Calcuatled Area missing from PowerPivot after upgrade

Tags: powerpivot

I've been using PowerPivot 32-Bit version with my Excel 2010 for months with no issues.

Today I installed MS Office 2010 64-Bit so I installed PP 64-Bit as well.  My problem, though, is the Calculations Area at the bottom is completely missing (the place where you enter measures).  For good measure, the Data View is gone too.

Any thoughts on what I could do to make the Calculations Area visible again?

TIA,

Kevin

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the calculation area in the home tab from MSDN help:
You must be in Data View. On the Home tab of the PowerPivot window, click Calculation Area in the View area. The Calculation Area appears below the table’s columns, and the Calculation Area button is highlighted and active.
see this help topic:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272048(v=sql.110).aspx

Also see the attached picture below:

[image]

What does it mean that you say there is now Data View? What do you see when you open the Power Pivot window?